# How do I make sure a class is added before getting the border width of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that when I use jQuery's `addClass` function adding a class with a 2px border, that it returns the old value at times and not the new when outputting the css in an iframe.  I assume that this happens only sometimes due to how fast the class gets added.  For example:

**Stylesheet:**

```
.testBorder {
   border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var iframe = $('#contentFrame').contents();
var obj = $('#someObj',iframe);
obj.addClass('testBorder');
console.log(obj.css('border-top-width')); 
console.log(obj.css('border-left-width'));
```

The border values outputted are often 0 instead of 2px.  I can do something like:

```
obj.delay(500).queue(function(){
   console.log($(this).css('border-top-width')); 
   console.log($(this).css('border-left-width'));
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```

But looking to apply it immediately after the class is added as I use the values to positon correctly to not look like its jumping.

The CSS is being applied and is reflected, so I know it is updating and not being overridden by another style.

The jQuery version I am using is 1.10.2 with the jQuery Migrate v1.2.1 and I am using the jQuery UI.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qLyha/ - It always outputs 2px. Maybe there is a class assigned to the element with 0px border that you need to remove?>

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Weird, I will have to play around a bit more.  I'm using 1.10.2 with the migrate.

Comment: could be the browser reacting slower compared to other browsers. I have experience similar issues. For this particular issue, you can probably use box-sizing:border-box; and avoid the entire issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframe_content = ($.browser.msie ? $('#contentFrame').get(0).contentWindow.document) : $('#contentFrame').get(0).contentDocument));
var obj = iframe_content.find('#someObj');
obj.queue(function() { /** check for border width here **/ });
obj.addClass('testBorder').dequeue(); /* this last .dequeue() may not be necessary */
```

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Comment: Make sure there are no selectors with higher specificity overriding your border styles.

Comment: yep I know.  The style applies to the object, just gives me the old value initially.  With the delay, it works fine.

Comment: the .done() callback should be called after the addClass finishes applying the styles to the DOM. If not, try doing this: `if (! obj.hasClass('testBorder')) { obj.toggleClass('testBorder', 0).promise()... }`

Comment: I realized that it's from a parent to an iframe, which is probably where the delay is.  Can you have another look at this?  I tried what you mentioned and it still doesn't always get the correct value.

Comment: that shouldn't be the cause of the delay. is this happening in every browser or only specific ones? You should do something like: `var iframe_content = ($.browser.msie ? $(iframe).get(0).contentWindow.document) : $(iframe).get(0).contentDocument));` to determine the actual content of the iframe

Comment: No to a div inside the iframe.

Comment: Thinking about it, you had the right idea using the queue. I've updated my answer to show you the correct way to use the queue in this instance.

Comment: If I put console.log outputs before each and inside queue, the queue goes before the addClass.

Comment: are you using jqueryUI by any chance?

Comment: also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qLyha/11/ - with a better use scenario. Dunno why it doesn't, but what I'm doing there *should* work.

Comment: The jQuery version I am using is 1.10.2 with the jQuery Migrate v1.2.1 and I am using the jQuery UI.  In Firefox 22.0, your example shows 0px before and after.

Comment: Ah, that makes life easy then. Check out this update: http://jsfiddle.net/qLyha/16/ . jQueryUI extends the .toggleClass() method to accept a callback function that will run when it is finished applying styles. As you can see, it gets the correct values now.